# FoxitIOSRDK: not able to click on Hyperlink

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

I am using FoxitRDK framework for opening the pdf document in my App. In the  demo everything works fine apart from one thing: I am not able to click on hyperlink. I have go through the SDK document and the classes inside framework but can not able to fine the solution.

The document link is below:

http://www.foxitsdk.com/docs/mobile-pdf-sdk/developer_guide_ios.pdf

and here is my code

```
NSString* pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"getting_started_ios1" ofType:@"pdf"];
// Initialize a PDFDoc object with the path to the PDF file
FSPDFDoc* pdfdoc = [FSPDFDoc createFromFilePath:pdfPath];

// Initialize a FSPDFViewCtrl object with the size of the entire screen

pdfViewCtrl = [[FSPDFViewCtrl alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-60)];

[pdfViewCtrl registerDocEventListener:self];
[pdfViewCtrl registerPageEventListener:self];
[pdfViewCtrl registerGestureEventListener:self];


// Set the document to display
[pdfViewCtrl setDoc:pdfdoc];
// Add the pdfViewCtrl to the root view
[self.view addSubview:pdfViewCtrl];
extensionsManager= [[UIExtensionsManager alloc]initWithPDFViewControl:pdfViewCtrl];
pdfViewCtrl.extensionsManager = extensionsManager;

[extensionsManager registerAnnotEventListener:self];
[extensionsManager registerAnnotHandler:self];


//Search button

searchButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(280, 80, 80, 40)];
[searchButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[searchButton setTitle: @"Search" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[searchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showSearchBar)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:searchButton];
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Foxit support team after updating the version to 2.0 it works perfect.

I have got the solution.
Good luck Team.

Answer (score 1):

You need to added UI extensions component to your app.
you can refer to the step in section"2.4.5 Add support for Text Search, Bookmark, and Annotation" of the developer guide.

After added the UI extensions to you project, and Initialize it, the link will be work.

related code are here:

```
"#import "../uiextensions/UIExtensionsManager.h"

UIExtensionsManager* extensionsManager;

...

extensionsManager = [[UIExtensionsManager alloc] initWithPDFViewControl:pdfViewCtrl];

pdfViewCtrl.extensionsManager = extensionsManager;"
```

If you want to Goto special page when a document open, you need to do it in the onDocOpened event.

```
(void)onDocOpened:(FSPDFDoc*)document error:(int)error
{
    [_pdfViewCtrl gotoPage:2 animated:false];
}
```

Comment: I have edit my question .even in demo code it is not working

Comment: [pdfViewCtrl gotoPage:3 animated:true]; need to be  call in the  onDocOpened event.

Comment: Thanks Amy but my problem is diffrent  Related to Hyperlink

Comment: could you send me a sample document, which kinds of link can't works?

Comment: Foxit RDK support the Link Annotation. But in V1.0 you download public, the URL link doesn't work. The V2.0 which is coming soon will support URL link.

Comment: Foxit RDK support the Link Annotation. But in V1.0 you download public, the URL link doesn't work. The V2.0 which is coming soon will support URL link for iOS.  You can't contact foxit to get more information.

Comment: Not sure why i can't delete/edit my comment. I mean,  you can contact foxit to get more information. you can test you document with completely_viewer demo and if that demo doesn't works, too. Not the problem of your code.

Comment: I have already created a token but they can't able to tell me the exact solution in mail they told that need to call there support team

Comment: It will be works in v2.0, and the internal version is OK. I think you can contact Foxit for more information.

Comment: Ok thanks for your support . Hope they will resolve this soon.

Comment: Hi guru, I don't believe I have received an email from you, don't hesitate to contact me if we can assist you.

Comment: @Rowan i got it in V2 now it works . Thanks for quick support.